# SqlStatement with 'Where' dont get row (Row exist!)

Tags: sql

i have this code but when I debug I'm not able to get into the `dr.Read()`

```
MembershipUser User = new MembershipUser();

SqlConnection conn = 
    new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager
                          .ConnectionStrings["MVCForumContext"]
                          .ConnectionString);
conn.Open();

using (var GetName = new SqlCommand(
    "SELECT * FROM MembershipUser WHERE UserName = @UserName", conn
)){
    GetName.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Name);

    using (SqlDataReader dr = GetName.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            User.Id = dr.GetGuid(dr.GetOrdinal("Id"));
        }
    }
}
conn.Close();
```

I know that rows exist but it dont seem to work, what could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative (bad practice - allows SQL injection attacks) to allow you to test: Try changing this line:

```
using (var GetName = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MembershipUser WHERE UserName ='" + Name + "'", conn))
```

and remove :

```
GetName.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Name);
```

OR just change your parameter `@UserName` to `UserName` as

```
GetName.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", Name);
```

Comment: Your first suggestion is very, very bad advice. Concatenating parameter values into SQL commands forces a hard parse the statement every time it is executed. And last but not least, this is an invitation to SQL injection attacks - try using `' or 1=1 --` as the value for the user parameter.

Comment: agree. added for completeness + changed advice.